# save variable name and result into string, split and compare - but doesnt work

Tags: php

I wanna load variables from a file as string and compare it later

**structure of file**:
variable name; result

e.g.,

```
$arr['x'];5
$a;53
$b - $a;27
```

I load this file (works) and assign first item after split to $x, e.g.,

```
$x = "$arr['x']";
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

```
$result = 5; // 2nd item of split - loaded from file line (ok)
```

and then compare

```
if ($result == $x)
{
    echo "ok";
}
```

or can't this be done?
PS: minimal example - that's why i removed loading from file and split

Comment: What is the purpose of this file?  There may be better ways to do this such as saving an array in a PHP file.

Comment: _"variables from a file"_ - it's not a variable when it's in a file. It's just a string. Is there an equivalent in the php script maybe? This sounds very much like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have expressions in your variables you will either need to write an expression parser or use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). This is how you can make it work with `eval`:

```
$vars = array("\$arr['x'];5", "\$a;53", "\$b - \$a;27");
$arr['x'] = 5;
$a = 54;
$b = 81;
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    list($x, $result) = explode(';', $var);
    if (eval("return $result == $x;")) {
        echo "$x = $result\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "$x != $result\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
$arr['x'] = 5 
$a != 53
$b - $a = 27
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XMoCg)

Comment: tnx to all and tnx to you nick & eval - i tried it some hours before too but i forgot to use the ";" within the string ... so you solved it and saved my day - tnx a lot

Comment: will do it - but i need more reputation

Comment: @Robert you don't need any reputation to accept an answer (the tick symbol under the voting arrows), only to use the voting arrows, and you will actually gain reputation (2 points) by accepting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0):

Why you have written enclosed `$arr['x']` with double quotation marks like this

```
$x = "$arr['x']";
```

Remove quotation marks from this statement and make it like this

```
$x = $arr['x'];
```

Comment: it only shows that it is a string which comes from the file